# Why would this call to sscanf() match one argument too many?

Tags: embedded, scanf, ecos

We use the `sscanf()` function under the eCos operating system to parse a command-line command provided by the user. We have code that essentially does this:

```
char[20] arg1 = "";
float arg2;
char[20] arg3 = "";
int n = sscanf(buffer + offset, "%4s %f %3s", arg1, &arg2, arg3); // offset is length of command plus 1 for the space
if (n == 3) { /* success */ } else { /* error */ };
```

But when called with a command buffer containing `command arg1 40.0`, the `success` branch is entered even though only two arguments were provided to the command. We would have expected the `error` branch to be executed.

Using plenty of `printf()` statements, here are the values of the variables after the call to `sscanf()`:

```
buffer = "command arg1 40.0"
arg1 = "arg1"
arg2 = 40.0
arg3 = ""
```

We are unable to reproduce this behavior with unit tests. Before we start suspecting a broken `sscanf()` implementation, can there be another explanation?

**UPDATE**

The eCos operating system implements its own version of the C standard library. Below is the code fragment that handles the `%s` format specifier. I don't know if it helps but we are more and more confident there might be a bug here.

```
 139 #define CT_STRING       2       /* %s conversion */
 ....
 487         switch (c)
 ....
 597         case CT_STRING:
 598             /* like CCL, but zero-length string OK, & no NOSKIP */
 599             if (width == 0)
 600                 width = ~0;
 601             if (flags & SUPPRESS)
 602             {
 603                 n = 0;
 604                 while (!isspace (*CURR_POS))
 605                 {
 606                     n++, INC_CURR_POS;
 607                     if (--width == 0)
 608                         break;
 609                     if (BufferEmpty)
 610                         break;
 611                 }
 612                 nread += n;
 613             }
 614             else
 615             {
 616                 p0 = p = va_arg (ap, char *);
 617                 while (!isspace (*CURR_POS))
 618                 {
 619                     *p++ = *CURR_POS;
 620                     INC_CURR_POS;
 621                     if (--width == 0)
 622                         break;
 623                     if (BufferEmpty)
 624                         break;
 625                 }
 626                 *p = 0;
 627                 nread += p - p0;
 628                 nassigned++;
 629             }
 630             continue;
```

Comment: *"We are unable to reproduce this behavior with unit tests."* I am unable to reproduce this error either, even with a hopeful trailing `newline` after the arguments in the entered string (although not using eCos). Please provide a MCVE which demonstrates the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you also printf() the value of `offset`?